# This app has been removed from Google Play for violating the Impersonation and Intellectual Property policy

Tags: android, google-play

Hi everyone I have submitted an app to Playstore and after 5 days of wait time the app was up and live. Well after few hours I have received an email saying that my app was removed due to following reason.

> This app has been removed from Google Play for violating the
>   Impersonation and Intellectual Property policy. Before submitting your
>   app for another review, read through the Unauthorised Use of
>   Copyrighted Content section of the policy and remove any content owned
>   by a third party from your app.

The app is basically Free Movies app. There are so many apps already present on PlayStore such as

- [hdmoviesfree](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ananentertainment.hdmoviesfree)
- [HD movies](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.harry.hd.movies)

And many more, Now my question is why these app are still live while mine was removed.

Answer (score 0):

checked the apps you provided and they are clearly violating copyright use as far as i know. The name of your app can also cause problems but it is not stated in the warning you got. I am thinking of the API that you are using might be causing problems. When google play store detects any private API that is illegal they can do this to your app.
where are the videos streamed from? The video contents can be streamed from direct sources that can possibly contain malicious software. I am not sure but a different API or the source of stream, might be the reason that these guys are still online and you're not.

Comment: I have used firebase as database and I am using my own hosting and all the video files are stored there and they are played through googles ExoPlayer itself. I am not using any third party APIs that can cause this issue, first i have uploaded with the screenshots containing the actual posters of movies and I didn’t got rejected. Now i have blurred out all the posters even.

Comment: well hope it works out this time, blurring can work. It's just weird how google play store examine the apps. first they accept it and after some time ,in your case 5 days, they find something violating. My friend had his app on the store for over 2 years, now they took it down because it had the "stalk" word in its name. there are still apps that have the word "stalk" in them. it's just weird and unconsistent.